# Using a class as a namespace for the entire file

Tags: ruby, class, namespaces

When you want to use module `A` as a namespace to work within for the entire file, you can just put:

```
include A
```

and whatever follows will be within `A`. Is there a way to do a similar thing with class `B`?

Putting:

```
class B
```

at the beginning of the file, and after all contents of the file, ending the file all the way down with

```
end
```

does not look elegant, and is a cause of mistake. I am looking for a way that does not require a closing command like `end`.

**Edit** My description above about `include A` seemed to be wrong. Even after doing so, the environment is still the main object. What I want is to make it possible so that if I just do

```
def foo; ... end
```

without any explicit nesting, then that will be defined as a method to `A` or `B` for the respective cases.

Comment: You want to basically have a directive that will be processed at the top of the file that will make the remainder of the file live under a symbol defined by that directive?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes. That is what I want.

Comment: It was wrong to ask this question. I had been confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me best knowledge, there is no such directive.

Though if your files are going to "executed" by another script what you can do is this:

File `file.rb` contains

```
puts self
```

File `main.rb` contains

```
class B
    eval(File.read('file.rb'))
end
```

If you like to make this more transparent, you might even provide your own implementation of require which hides all this magic.